# Load only Iframe instead of whole HTML page

Tags: html, iframe

Is there a way that I can load only Iframe on button click instead of whole HTML page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is Your tried code?

Answer (score 0):

Within your `onclick` handler just:

```
document.getElementById("iframe_id").contentWindow.location.reload();
```

or

```
document.getElementById("iframe_id").src = document.getElementById("iframe_id").src
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
onClick='document.getElementById("ifr").src="add_dossier.php";'
```

or

```
$(function(){
    $('#button').click(function(){
        if(!$('#iframe').length) {
                $('#iframeHolder').html('<iframe id="iframe" src="http://google.com" width="700" height="450"></iframe>');
        }
    });   
});
```